# How to define event handler function to combine event listeners

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a webpage for a simple tax calculation for which the javascript is as below. I have a question that states

1. Define an event handler function that will be connected to the calculate button. This is
   where you should do all your calculations and then put the results in the sales tax and
   total fields. You will also need to do some basic validation on the data in the subtotal
   and tax rate fields, see bullet below.
2. Define an event handler function that will be connected to the clear button. In this
   function you should clear out all the fields and then put the cursor back in the subtotal
   field so it is ready for new input. Look into how to set focus on a form element.
3. Define an event handler function that will be used to initialize or setup the app. This
   event handler will only need the code to bind the other two event listeners to the
   buttons. In this function add event listeners, for click events, to the two buttons and call
   the correct event handler function for each. What should I do for question 3?

   ```
   <script>
         function calcTax() {
           console.log("Tax Calculator works");
           let mySubtotal = Number(document.getElementById("subtotal").value);
           let myTaxRate = Number(document.getElementById("taxRate").value);

           if (isNaN(mySubtotal)) {
             alert("Subtotal should be a number to Calculate Tax");
             document.getElementById("subtotal").value = "";
             document.getElementById("subtotal").focus();
           } else if (mySubtotal <= 0) {
             alert("Subtotal should be greater than 0");
             document.getElementById("subtotal").value = "";
             document.getElementById("subtotal").focus();
           } else if (isNaN(myTaxRate)) {
             alert("Tax Rate should be a number to Calculate Tax");
             document.getElementById("taxRate").value = "";
             document.getElementById("taxRate").focus();
           } else if (myTaxRate <= 0 || myTaxRate > 20) {
             alert("Tax Rate should be between 0 and 20");
             document.getElementById("taxRate").value = "";
             document.getElementById("taxRate").focus();
           } else {
             document.getElementById("salesTax").value =
               (mySubtotal * myTaxRate) / 100;
             document.getElementById("mytotal").value =
               mySubtotal + (mySubtotal * myTaxRate) / 100;
           }
         }

         document.getElementById("taxCalc").addEventListener("click", calcTax);
         document.getElementById("clearBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
             document.getElementById("subtotal").value = "";
             document.getElementById("subtotal").focus();
             document.getElementById("taxRate").value = "";
             document.getElementById("salesTax").value = "";
             document.getElementById("mytotal").value = "";
           });

         window.onload = function () {
           document.getElementById("subtotal").focus();
         };
       </script>
   ```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but you can use a single event handler for multiple events with `onEvent=handle` and `onOtherEvent=handle` and defining a function called `handle()`.

Comment: i have modified my question. I completed the first 2 questions but am not sure what should be done for the last one

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `addEventListener` calls into a new function, and you should create a function for the action of the clear button so that you can also call it "yourself":

```
function clear() {
    document.getElementById("subtotal").value = "";
    document.getElementById("subtotal").focus();
    document.getElementById("taxRate").value = "";
    document.getElementById("salesTax").value = "";
    document.getElementById("mytotal").value = "";
}

function init() {
    document.getElementById("taxCalc").addEventListener("click", calcTax);
    document.getElementById("clearBtn").addEventListener("click", clear);
    clear(); // also call immediately as part of the initialisation
}
```

And on `window.onload` you would call `init()`:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Note that now on page load  `init` will be called, which will call `clear`, which will set the focus.